# Use of unresolved identifier 'FBAppEvents'

Tags: ios, facebook, swift

I'm trying to implement a Facebook events system. To do so, I have added the FacebookSDK in my bridge file this way:

```
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
```

And I'm trying to run the following method of the `FBAppEvents` class:

```
FBAppEvents.logEvent(aCategory, parameters: ["_eventAction": aAction, "_eventLabel": aLabel])
```

But for some reason I'm getting the error described in the title.

**UPDATE:**

**==============**

I have two targets in this project: an **app** and a **keyboard extension**.
The file that I'm trying to use `FBAppEvents` in, is a tracking analytics class that is used by both projects (targets).

If I copy this file to the second target and configure each file to support it's target the the problem disappears but that makes me to duplicate files in the project that are used by both targets, which is something I'm really trying to avoid.

Does someone knows how this can be done without the duplication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this issue was to add Facebook framework to the bridge file of the extensions as well as the bridge file of the applications.

Surely the framework needs to be configured in the **Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries** section of both the application and the extension otherwise you will receive the "Use of unresolved identifier" error even if the framework is configured in one of the targets.